# Update only one array value from another array in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs

There are two arrays that I'm getting through two different functions and services from MongoDB.

One array (rolesList) is used to fill a select box and the other (userList) to fill a table. The thing is that the collection from where this last array is obtained has only the role id and I need to print the role name to the table, since I already have the data I need a way to get the role name from the rolesList array and update userList.role with it.

What would be the best way to do it?
I leave a code snippet so you can hopefully understand my problem better.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.userList = [ { _id: 'ae21e1f0663dddf0c6e5e8b',
    fullname: 'Cosme Fulanito',
    lastname: 'Fulanito',
    lastname2: '',
    email: 'cosme.fulanito@mail.com',
    role: 'ADMIN_APPLICANT_PROFILE', //this is the _id on rolesList and I need to print the name
    name: 'Cosme' },
  { _id: 'ae21e4b0663dddf0c6e5e8d',
    fullname: 'Benito Camelo',
    lastname: 'Camelo',
    lastname2: '',
    email: 'benito.camelo@mail.com',
    role: 'PURCHASER_PROFILE',
    name: 'Benito' } ]


$scope.rolesList = [ {
_id: "ADMIN_APPLICANT_PROFILE",
name: "Administrador solicitante"
},
{
_id: "PURCHASER_PROFILE",
name: "Comprador" } ]

   
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div class="request-table-overflow">
      <table class="table m-b-none">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Tipo de Cuenta</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
          <tr ng-repeat="row in userList" st-select-row="row">
            <td class="text-muted"><span class="badge bg-black">{{$index +1}}</span></td>
            <td>{{row.email}}</td>
            <td>{{row.role}}</td> <!--This need to be updated to display the value of rolesList.name-->
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td>{{row.lastname}}</td>
            <td>
              <h5 ng-click="details(row._id)">
                             <span class="text-muted">Ver detalle </span>
                             <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                           </h5>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal approach for situations like this is to use an object as a dictionary.

To do so you can change your `rolesList` to look like this:

```
$scope.rolesList = {
    "ADMIN_APPLICANT_PROFILE": "Administrador solicitante",
    "PURCHASER_PROFILE": "Comprador" 
}
```

Then in your table row you can reference the role name using the role value

```
<td>{{ rolesList[row.role] }}</td>
```

If you can't change the format of rolesList you can create the dictionary with the following loop

```
$scope.roleListDict = {};
angular.forEach($scope.rolesList, function(role, roleIndex) {
    $scope.roleListDict[role._id] = role.name;
});
```

And

```
<td>{{ roleListDict[row.role] }}</td>
```

Comment: "since I already have the data I need a way to get the role name from the rolesList array and update userList.role with it." So I'm assuming they can't change the array.

Comment: @Salix updated with how you can create the dictionary keeping the same format of the `rolesList`.  Then if you do the `roleListDict` method you will need to change the `<td>` tag to `roleListDict[row.role]`

Comment: that creates a 3rd array, my updated solution just changed the existing array. Also, I haven't been able to make {{ rolesList[row.role] }} work. I didn't know you could reference another array than the one mentionned in ng-repeat. It could be pratical. Altho, now that I think about it, wouldn't you run in the same problem as my first answer if the order is different?

Comment: It's not an array, it is an object.  `Object.name === Object[name]`, but you need to use `Object[name]` if `name` is dynamic.  `{{ rolesList[row.role] }}` will only work if you change the format of `rolesList` like I did in my answer.  Otherwise you need to do the `forEach` and use `{{ roleListDict[row.role] }}`

Comment: I created a working fiddle here using the roleListDict method and it works. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1ew69qa/4/)

Comment: Wow! lots of things to consider here. Thanks a lot to both of you for your help.